# MSYS2 home folder: show ~

Tags: bash, msys, msys2

I've just installed MSYS2, and to have it use my Windows user folder as $HOME, I put this in /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
HOME=$USERPROFILE
```

And that works fine when I just run cd, except the prompt doesn't show ~ anymore as the current path when I'm there. Another problem is that

```
cd ~
```

takes me to my home dir, but pressing tab after ~ doesn't expand it with the contents of my home directory; intead I get a list of my computer's users prefixed by ~, and trying to access one of those makes it try to cd to /home/(username).

How can I get ~ to play nice with a home directory that doesn't reside in /home?

Comment: What if you type `~/` and then Tab? (It *shouldn't* expand with the contents of your home directory if you type `~` and then Tab; it sounds like it's doing the right thing.)

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. ~/ and tab doesn't expand at all.

Comment: How about `~/ta` and then Tab, where you have a file in your home directory whose name begins with `ta`?

Comment: Same there, doesn't expand.

Comment: is your username tacospice?  what if you type ~tac<tab>... does that expand to a full "~tacospice"?  To expand that, put it in an 'echo'.  This reminds me of the issue of whether or not bach should expand variables when doing prompt completion.  Some think yes, some think not... I think it became an obscure option.   Might be similar for ~, but don't think it is usually expanded.  What does "echo ~" print out?

Comment: Ahh! That brought me to the answer. Naturally, $USERPROFILE contains the path to the home directory in *Windows* format, and for some reason, MSYS2's cd still accepts Windows style paths, but then brings me to the mounted location. So I was essentially doing "cd C:\Users\<user>" and then getting redirected to /c/Users/<user>. Setting $HOME with the proper path makes everything work normally (~ in the prompt, ~/ expansion). Feel free to post it in the form of an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: A working value for $HOME is HOME=/c/Users/$USER in bashrc (at least on Windows 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$USERPROFILE** points to the user's home folder in *Windows* format, but obviously MSYS would expect a *UNIX* style path. I'd read the suggestion in another post, possibly on here, which is why I tried it.

For some reason, cd:ing to a Windows path in MSYS's bash will bring you to the correct mounted location of that folder, but then you will no longer be in the path specified by **$HOME**, which I believe is why the suggestion works, but still doesn't substitute the path for ~ in the prompt.

After that situtation dawned on me (thanks in part to Astara), I came up with this instead:

```
HOME=/c/Users/$USER
```

in /etc/bash.bashrc, or whichever bashrc file applies, in case you're not using MSYS2.

Of course, this requires your users folder to be C:\Users, as is the case on at least Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: You may still be able to make `$USERPROFILE` work. Try this: `HOME=$(cd "$USERPROFILE" && pwd)`.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to do this is to put this into /etc/nssswitch.conf :

```
db_home: windows
```

See [here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch) for docs.

Also to make my homedir ls output more readable, I put this in ~/.bashrc :

```
alias ls="ls -h --color=auto --hide='ntuser.*' --hide='NTUSER.*'"
```

Comment: In my corporate environment, this put it on a network drive for me, not the local C:\Users, which is what I wanted.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to configure that line to `db_home: /c/Users/%U` to override the home path.  Ref: http://kflu.github.io/2017/07/18/2017-07-18-msys2/

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/fstab` to mount `C:\Users` as `/home` and voila!
For example, append the following at the end of `fstab`:

```
C:/Users /home ntfs binary,noacl,auto 1 1
```

Comment: After reading about the format referenced at Cygwin(https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table), I am curious about the choices on the third column here. `binary` is fine, `auto` is ignored so can be omitted. What's the advantage of `noacl` over `acl`? It seems cygwin is able to construct POSIX permissions from NTFS ones. Is it just to keep in line with default `cygdrive` settings?

Comment: Well, that was a while ago when I had to write some code in a Win64 environment; honestly, I can't recall the reason :-)

Comment: Upon further reading, apparently the conversion done with `acl` is not good. I guess it's good enough to use `binary,noacl`.

Comment: @FRIdSUN `acl` is bad if you have mixed cygwin (or msys)/windows uses of files and directories. Msys by default mounts drives `noacl`, cygwin `acl` This is, presumably, because the cygwin crew, mistakenly, assume that people stay in the cygwin environment all the time and do not use Windows tools in the same directories where they use cygwin. cygwin manipulates the access control lists in non-standard ways in order to emulate POSIX permissions on files (there is no 1:1 relation to NTFS file attributes). Bottom line is, for typical mixed use mount `noacl`.