# How do you set up MSYS2 to work like git for windows but with zsh?

Tags: windows, git, zsh, msys

Since the [devs for git-for-windows are adamant of not expanding the installation size by 2MB to support `zsh`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2023#issuecomment-455644182) I am trying to see if I can just do it through msys2.  So I can get zsh with the `git-auto-fetch` plugin running.

I am trying to make it so that it behaves like git for windows.  Here's the list of things I am doing in terms of difficulty.

I installed the packages as `pacman -S zsh git`

1. I am able to use `git` within msys2 but not outside.  Likely I just need to add a path somewhere.
2. msys2 sets its own path ignoring Windows for the most part.  So things I install in `scoop` are not available.
3. I haven't been able to change the default shell to zsh yet.  But I think that's just a minor thing.
4. It uses it's own HOME folder not %UserProfile%.  I gotten the HOME folder issue resolved though using  [MSYS2 home folder: show ~](https://superuser.com/questions/809974/msys2-home-folder-show) by setting `db_home: windows` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
5. `git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` when using against a repo that utilized credential manager

Also I have noted that accessing a directory that was done in git-for-windows before when I do `git status` it shows all files modified

msys2 also takes over the `Shift-Insert` key combination so I can't paste from clipboard using that combination.

`git log` does not page, it just shows everything.